# Source local file to HDFS sink by using flume

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I am using flume to Source local file to HDFS sink, below is my conf:

```
# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = /usr/download/test_data/
a1.sources.r1.basenameHeader = true
a1.sources.r1.basenameHeaderKey = fileName

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://172.16.10.5/user/admin/Data/
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{fileName}
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.idleTimeout=60

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 10000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 5000

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

And I used the user 'flume' to execute this conf file.

```
time bin/flume-ng agent -c conf -f conf/hdfs_sink.conf -n a1 -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

But it shows I could not find the local file, permission denied

```
Could not find file: /usr/download/test_data/sale_record0501.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/download/test_data/.flumespool/.flumespool-main.meta (Permission denied)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Permission denied? Can you add the output of `ls -lR /usr/download/test_data`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `flume` user may not have permission under the spooling directory. Your spooling directory is at `/usr` and It may be require a root permission to access this path.

First become a root with `sudo su` then execute or replace your execution command with

```
sudo bin/flume-ng agent -c conf -f conf/hdfs_sink.conf -n a1 -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

On the other hand, you can give permission to `flume` user with

```
cd /usr/download/
sudo chown -R flume:somegroup test_data
```